# Adding a prefix/suffix to an XML property's value in shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to write a shell script to properly format a string. To be more specific, I'm given a string property in this format:

```xml
<property name="resource" value="example"/>
```

And I'm trying to write a shell script that would change it into this:

```xml
<property name="resource" value="$R{example}"/>
```

I have to do this across multiple properties and the "example" string is different across all these properties.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is this input part of a larger (presumably XML) file, or is it just a one-line string? Do you control the code doing the generation (to be able to make assertions about precise representation), or do you need to be able to perform the same operation with any semantically-equivalent input?

Comment: Do you want to do this with *any* property, or only any property with a `name` of `resource`?

Comment: 1) This input is part of a larger XML file
2) I do not control the code I just need to be able to perform the same operation with semantically-equivalent input
3) Only doing this with a property of name "resource"
I believe your solution covers this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML documents should be edited with XML-aware tools. One such tool built for use from shell is [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/).

```
xml='<property name="resource" value="example"/>'

xmlstarlet ed -O \
  -u '//property[@name="resource"]/@value' \
  -x 'concat("$R{", ., "}")' \
  <<<"$xml"
```

...properly emits:

```
<property name="resource" value="$R{example}"/>
```

If you wanted to do this for *all* properties, rather than only those named `resource`, remove the `[@name="resource"]` clause, making the relevant argument just `-u //property/@value`.

Comment: Where do you get `xmlstarlet` from?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, see edit adding a link -- though I haven't seen a distro that didn't at least have an optional package for it in quite some time.

Comment: Welcome to the world of RHEL 5.3 ... a relic from the past!

Comment: Oh, my. Yeah, you might need to find an archived EPEL repository for it then.

Comment: (...actually, RHEL 5.3 might be old enough that my query wouldn't work without some tweaks with an XMLStarlet build from the same era -- IIRC, once upon a time, only single-quotes were valid for string literals, so it might have to be `-u "//property[@name='resource']/@value" -x "concat('\$R{', ., '}')"` or such).

Comment: I'd go with a source build rather than a package download if there was any problem like that.  It does require libxml2 and libxslt in a recent version, which would also be built.  And that's just (one of) my work machine(s).  My VM at home is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Centos, or ...